# PlanetScale doesnt let me create a new deploy request?

Tags: mysql, database, prisma, planetscale

I just pushed a schema change to our dev branch on planet scale. Then wanted to go through the deploy request, but ran into an error:

[image]

I understood what the problem was and fixed it. Then pushed again to our dev branch. But now there is no option to create a new deploy request to main? I am really stuck now, don't know what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Only one deploy request can be open at a time per development branch.

If you close the open deploy request (click the `Complete` button), you will be able to open up another one.